# How to calculate Pandas Dataframe size on disk before writing as parquet?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, pyarrow

Using python 3.9 with Pandas 1.4.3 and PyArrow 8.0.0.

I have a couple parquet files (all with the same schema) which I would like to merge up to a certain threshold (not fixed size, but not higher than the threshold).

I have a directory, lets call it `input` that contains parquet files.

Now, if I use `os.path.getsize(path)` I get the size on disk, but merging 2 files and taking the sum of that size (i.e os.path.getsize(path1) + os.path.getsize(path2)) naturally won't yield good result due to the metadata and other things.
I've tried the following to see if I can have some sort of indication about the file size before writing it into parquet.

```
print(df.info())
print(df.memory_usage().sum())
print(df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum())
print(sys.getsizeof(df))
print(df.values.nbytes + df.index.nbytes + df.columns.nbytes)
```

Im aware that the size is heavily depended on compression, engine, schema, etc, so for that I would like to simply have a factor.
Simply put, if I want a threshold of 1mb per file, ill have a 4mb actual threshold since I assume that the compression will compress the data by 75% (4mb -> 1mb)

So in total i'll have something like

```
compressed_threshold_in_mb = 1
compression_factor = 4
```

and the condition to keep appending data into a merged dataframe would be by checking the multiplication of the two, i.e:

```
if total_accumulated_size > compressed_threshold_in_mb * compression_factor:
```

assuming `total_accumulated_size` is the accumulator of how much the dataframe will weigh on disk

Comment: Does this solve your problem https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html?

Comment: also see `pandas_df.info()`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah memory won't reflect the size on disk. size on disk is generally higher from what i saw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data frame to parquet in memory to have an exact idea of how much data it is going to use:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

def get_parquet_size(df: pd.DataFrame) -> int:
    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        df.to_parquet(buffer)
        return buffer.tell()
```

Comment: Not optimized to heavy files, but since im dealing with KBs that works for me.
Obviously in GBs that will be an issue